# How to call javascript on button click Odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo-16

I want to call a javascript on a button click, I tried a lot of examples and it didn't work. The button needs a name and the associated functions run on the server sides, I want the event to run on the client side only.

Comment: Here is a solution using the owl odoo framework. https://github.com/binyama/button_to_call_js_odoo.git

Answer (score 1):

**if you’re using  Odoo v8**

```
$(document).on('click', $('button:has(span:contains(Text Inside Button))'), function() {
    console.log('call function here');
});
```

Comment: I use odoo version 16